# Change Data Capture errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cdc, change-data-capture

Am trying to get the net changes on CDC enabled table by passing Min and Max dates.  But is throwing below error.

```
Msg 313, Level 16, State 3, Line 24
An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_ ... .
```

My code is as below:

```
DECLARE @CDate DATE = '2013-03-18' --This is the date after the CDC was enabled on the table
DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @lsnStartDatetime DATETIME;
DECLARE @lsnEndDateTime DATETIME;

DECLARE @begin_time DATETIME ,
@end_time DATETIME ,
@from_lsn BINARY(10) ,
@to_lsn BINARY(10);


SELECT  @lsnStartDatetime = CAST(CAST(@CDate AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
SELECT  @lsnEndDateTime = CAST(CAST(@CDate AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' 23:59:59' AS DATETIME)


SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than or equal',
                                       @lsnStartDatetime);
SET @to_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal',
                                     @lsnEndDateTime);

if exists (select * from sys.objects where name = 'EmployeeCDCbyDate' and type = 'u')
drop table etl.EmployeeCDCbyDate
SELECT  *
FROM    cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_employee(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, N'all')
```

Is it the from_lsn and to_lsn getting from sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn doesnt match with is mapped aginst the cdc table 'employee'

Below code works fine; but it gets all net changes from min max lsn's.

```
DECLARE @min_lsn BINARY(10) = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn ('employee')
DECLARE @max_lsn BINARY(10) = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn ()
SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_employee(@min_lsn, @max_lsn, 'all') ORDER BY 1 desc
```

What i need is to get min and max lsn of cdc instance for given date and get the net changes for that date. Any clues?

**Edit:**

This works fine with first table when i enable on bunch of tables.

Ex:

```
USE ERP

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_db
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table @source_schema = N'dbo', 
@source_name = N'Employee', 
@capture_instance = 'Employee', 
@supports_net_changes =1, 
@role_name = NULL  

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table @source_schema = N'dbo', 
@source_name = N'StoreListing', 
@capture_instance = 'StoreListing', 
@supports_net_changes =1, 
@role_name = NULL

Go
```

This works fine with Employee table.  If i change the order in which they are CDC enabled (if i put storelist first and employee next), then it works fine with employee listing.

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer to a similar question on MSDN Social:  [Is there bug with cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_.... in SQL Server 2012](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/2629a56c-0f77-454f-aa02-7897b18d48da/).

It is marked as answered by a moderator. Here is quote:

> I tested in my server. When I ran the script in the SQL Server 2008 R2, it could be run successfully without error.
>
> When I ran the script in SQL Server 2012, the error message came out the same as yours. I think you could try to apply the latest SQL Server 2012 Service Pack to see if it would OK.

[And here is a bug report with Microsoft.](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/782085/is-there-bug-with-cdc-fn-cdc-get-net-changes-in-sql-server-2012) It is under investigation.

Comment: Those all on MSDN forum and on Connect were my posts though :-).  Am looking if anyone figured out alternate way to do this.

Comment: Sorry for that. I should have compared the code. That code in Edit, that works for first table - does it work for other tables?

Answer (score 0):

I received this message and the reason is because I had my Start LSN and Ending LSN numbers

I answered in more detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/30920333/98802