# Error while executing change data capture sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cdc, change-data-capture

I am getting this error 
"An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_" while trying to execute the following sql query.

```
use SpatialDB
go
declare @begin_time datetime, @end_time datetime, @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10);
set @begin_time=GETDATE()-1;
set @end_time=GETDATE();
set @from_lsn=sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than or equal', @begin_time);
set @to_lsn=sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest greater than or eqaul', @end_time);
select * from cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_Points(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, N'all');
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Late, but for future seekers . . .

The error message is somewhat misleading. The parameters that you pass in to the function need to be "valid" or you will get this frustrating error message.

Here is a quote from TechNet for SQL Server 2008 article [Using Change Data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645858%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). I recommend that you read this article.

> We recommend validating the LSN boundaries that are to be used in a TVF query before their use. Null endpoints or endpoints that lie
>   outside the validity interval for a capture instance will force an
>   error to be returned by a change data capture TVF.
>
> For example, the following error is returned for a query for all
>   changes when a parameter that is used to define the query interval is
>   not valid, or is out of range, or the row filter option is invalid.
>
> Msg 313, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>
> An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or
>   function cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_ ...
>
> The corresponding error returned for a net changes query is the
>   following:
>
> Msg 313, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>
> An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or
>   function cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_ ...

When I first began using these functions in SQL Server 2012, I was passing in wild parameters that were far outside the range of dates that had been captured by CDC. When I cleaned them up--that is, started using date ranges that were valid--good results followed.

Answer (score 0):

More Late, but for future seekers . . .

I received this message and the reason is because I had my Start LSN and Ending LSN numbers switched.  So, I switched them back and it worked fine.

I ended up with code like:

`SELECT DISTINCT sh.siteid1 AS 'Site Number'
    ,CASE cdc.__$operation
        WHEN 1
            THEN 'D'
        WHEN 2
            THEN 'I'
        WHEN 4
            THEN 'U'
        END AS CDC_OPERATION
FROM site_header sh(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_svt_svsiteheader(0x00004B04000019300002, 0x00004B0500003A220001, N'All') cdc ON cdc.site_id = sh.site_id
LEFT JOIN site_location sl ON sh.id_site = sl.id_site
    AND sh.primary_id = sl.id_rec`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and Gerald was spot on - if I use LSNs within the range of CDC captured data, no issue.

I'm now capping my LSN values with `sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('my_captureinstance')` and `sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()`, e.g:

```
DECLARE @begin_time DATETIME, @end_time DATETIME, @begin_lsn BINARY(10), @end_lsn BINARY(10), @min_lsn BINARY(10), @max_lsn BINARY(10);

SET @begin_time = '2015-06-23 00:00:00.000';
SET @end_time   = '2015-06-24 00:00:00.000';

SELECT @begin_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than', @begin_time);
SELECT @end_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', @end_time);

SELECT @min_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('my_captureinstance')
SELECT @max_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()

IF @begin_lsn < @min_lsn BEGIN
  SELECT @begin_lsn = @min_lsn
END

IF @end_lsn > @max_lsn BEGIN
  SELECT @end_lsn = @max_lsn
END

SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_my_captureinstance(@begin_lsn, @end_lsn, 'all')
```